# All Reflections in Blender are Completely Black in look dev mode

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, hdri

This is might be a mistake on my end since I am a near complete beginner at blender. I am trying to experiment with nodes, but all the reflections on the default hdri in look-dev mode show up completely black. Thanks in advance for any help.
[image: In this picture, I set the world opacity to 0, and made turned Metallic to 1 and Roughness to 0 on the principal bsdf, to show reflections.]

[image]

Comment: Some more information about the setup is that I made the world opacity 0, the metallic on my cube to 1 and the roughness to 0 on the Principal BSDF, to show reflections.

Comment: Hello :). This looks like compatibility issue. Even your HDRi preview is black, which shouldn't happen. Check [minimal requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/), and perhaps update your gpu drivers :).

Comment: I thought that as well, but if I switch to preview render mode, switch to cycles, and add an hdr all of the reflections work as expected.

Comment: Not a solution, but perhaps one of the [older versions](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) like 2.81./2.82 could work better? :)

Comment: I tried different versions earlier today, and none of them worked. Could you see if the .blend works in look dev mode for you?

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow and let you know :).

Comment: I guess that's caused by your graphics card. latest drivers?

Comment: I don't think that it is the cause because when I switch to cycles, it gives the expected results.

Comment: Hi. This site is not a regular forum, please don't add solved to the title. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour ... so please add an answer for future visitors and accept it. Thanks

Comment: Here is the bug report btw: https://developer.blender.org/T72124

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed my edit into an answer and am going to accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this was caused by a bug: https://developer.blender.org/T72124

I ended up fixing this problem by uninstalling *Blender 2.83* and installing a newer experimental version of *Blender 2.9x*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this only so I can post a screenshot. This is from my copy of blender (2.83) using the same settings you outlined. If all your settings are the identical, it's got to be some kind of bug or problem with your setup. See image:

[image: ReflectWorking]

EDIT - I downloaded your .blend file, changed nothing and took a screenshot. This is what I get - take is as you will:

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, It looks like all of our settings match

Comment: I'm just curious why the material "globe" in the bottom right corner has an image on it in mine, but yours is plain black. Do me a favor. go to your blender folder (../2.83/datafiles/studiolights/world) and make sure all the world environments are there (.exr files).

Comment: Yes, all the .exr's are there

Comment: In that top box, where you changed the world opacity, is there an image on the sphere?  What happens if you click it, do other ones come up you can choose from?

Comment: Yes, I see all of the different spheres, which I can select from.

Comment: Does picking a different one change anything? It's strange why it's not showing up in your viewport. No chance you have "scene lights" or "scene world" checked?

Comment: Picking a different one doesn't change anything, and I don't have any of those options checked.

Comment: Weird. Well, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Despite my attempts, I cannot replicate the exact issue. Perhaps someone else will come along who has seen this before. You can upload your.blend if you want, maybe that will make things easier - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hey, I downloaded your file and posted a screenshot in my answer. Given the image, i'm pretty sure it's a problem on your end. (It's the same in both eevee and cycles)