# Why isn’t my sphere turning metallic? (beginner)

Tags: materials, node-editor

why isn’t it turning metallic? i’m doing exactly what the tutorial guy is doing, our viewport shading is the same, i added my render setting in the next slide. i tried screen space reflections and it just makes a tiny pixelated bright spot but the rest is black. his is reflecting the hdri that comes with blender the one in the viewport and mine is not even though we have the same settings, why is that?. also on his screen he has a ball on the bottom right that shows the automatic hdri, and i do not

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"... a ball on the bottom right that shows the automatic hdri"* - that's the *HDRI Preview* option in the Overlays you need to activate it or go to Shading workspace (main tabs)

Comment: okay thanks, the ball is black even though i have the automatic hdri set up like he does

Comment: Might be a bug. Which Blender version do you use? I've seen similar questions about "black HDRI spheres" ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131649/blender-shaded-mode-view-problem and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185605/all-reflections-in-blender-are-completely-black-in-look-dev-mode

Comment: It's a light reflected in the sphere when you enable scene lights? (screenshot of 2nd answer of 1st question if you don't know how to enable it). Or get an HDRI from https://hdrihaven.com/ and use it in the world background. If it works then something could be wrong with the installation or preference settings.

Comment: i added an hdri and the hdri works but the metal ball is still black, with a tiny shiny dot. changing the roughness does nothing. it’s still just a black ball with a light brown shiny dot. it’s not reflecting the hdri. i had this issue with another project i was trying to do, it won’t reflect the hdri. when i activate scene lights  it goes from pitch black to shiny brown light again. not reflecting anything at all

Comment: also, in the question link you sent me the person said it could be due to their computers graphics card being old. i have a shitty $100 laptop so that could be the issue, some stuff may not be working. i remember blender telling me some stuff may not work because my computers graphics card. damn that’s really a bummer

Comment: Yes, could be your graphics card :-( The HDRI has light information. If this doesn't work for some reason nothing is reflected and the sphere appears black. You can try Cycles with CPU. This could work but it's slow and pixelated in the viewport.